# Duplicate URLs and solution in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

after years I discovered a bug in duplication URLs that I try to fix (author is gone) despite htaccess rule I thought should force it.

Issue:
I have the same content under 2 URLS, ex:

http://www.wrock.pl/news-23069/Depeche_Mode_Party_w_klubie_Liverpool_/

www.wrock.pl/index.php?s=news&d=23069&nazwa=Depeche_Mode_Party_w_klubie_Liverpool_

or shorter www.wrock.pl/index.php?s=news&d=23069

Another example are menu pages:

http://www.wrock.pl/koncerty/

www.wrock.pl/index.php?s=koncerty

I thought the "index.php" version should be hidden or redirected to friendly URL version, meanwhile both show with 200/OK
Index.php itself gets redirected OK: www.wrock.pl/index.php

Aim:
be able to show only friendly URl version (redirect the index.php version).
Google stopped indexing them so it may be an issue (one of many reasons).

Here is my htaccess responsible for presented examples:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wrock.pl(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.wrock.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

# REDIRECT index.php to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://www.wrock.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

#NEWS
RewriteRule ^news-([0-9]+)/([^-]+)/$ index.php?s=news&d=$1&nazwa=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?s=news&strona=$1 [L,NC]

#KONCERTY
RewriteRule ^koncerty/$ index.php?s=koncerty [L,NC]
```

I dont know if current redirections should be changes or should I enter something like:

```
#RewriteRule ^index.php?s=news&d=([0-9]+)&nazwa=([^-]+)$ http://www.wrock.pl/news-$1/$2/ [L,NC]
```

which doesn't work of course.

Thank You very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above your **`#NEWS`** items, you need to add these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?s=news&d=([0-9]+)&nazwa=([^-&\ ]+)($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /news-%1/%2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?s=news&strona=([0-9]+)($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /news/%1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?s=koncerty
RewriteRule ^ /koncerty/ [L,R=301]
```

And in order to handle the *"shorter `www.wrock.pl/index.php?s=news&d=23069`"*:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?s=news&d=([0-9]+)($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /news-%1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^news-([0-9]+)/$ index.php?s=news&d=$1 [L]
```